# Java sending bulk mail, very slow

Tags: java, performance, email, mail-server

In my mailing application I want to send bulk mails to a lot of people. 
Let's take 1.000 people so 1.000 mails.

I already tried to reduce the amount by putting people into CC, but the application is taking more time to sending the mail and the speed is exactly the same as before.

Let's take a mail is taking 3 à 4 seconds,
So: 1.000 * 3s = 3000s or 50Min

Is there a faster way to sending these mails?

My code:

```
public String sendMailWithCC(java.lang.String to,java.lang.String[] cc, java.lang.String from, java.lang.String message, java.lang.String title, java.util.ArrayList attachments){

        boolean succes = false;
//          Get system properties
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-relay.com");
//          Get Session
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
        String errorMessage = "";
//             Define message

        Message mailmsg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            mailmsg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            mailmsg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

            for(int i = 0; i<cc.length ; i++){
                mailmsg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc[i]));
            }


            mailmsg.setSubject(title);

            // create the message part 
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            //fill message
            messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


            // Put parts in message
            mailmsg.setContent(multipart);


//              Send message
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

//              authentication with mail server
            transport.connect();
            transport.sendMessage(mailmsg, mailmsg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();

            succes = true;

        }catch (Exception e){
            errorMessage = e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if(succes == true){
            return null;
        }else{
            return "ERROR when sending email " + errorMessage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all, use BCC instead of CC. You don't want the recipients to see who else got the email.

Comment: Use a third party service to send bulk emails. Save yourself the headaches.

Comment: Do you know free third party services for e-mailing?